# Russian roullette no reshuffling probability

Tags: probability

What are the odds of playing Russian roulette alone surviving to $5$ consecutive trial without reshuffling?

If the event were independent it would be $(5/6)\cdot (4/5)\dotsb (1/2) = 1/6$.
But are the event independent? You must survive previously to be able to play the next move?

I  am not sure how to compute from there.

The Intersection of dependents events is $P(E∩F) = P(E) * P(F|E)$.
$F$ and $E$ being surviving first and second trial respectfully.
Is that correct?
How computing  $P(F|E)$? Is it $F*E$ ?

Am I correct? So the result would be $P(G∩H∩I∩E∩F)$?
(with $G$ $H$ $I$ the fifth forth and third trial.)
I just don't know how to compute that.

I would really appreciate more than the number the method.

Any helps or tips appreciated!

Comment: As there is no reshuffling, your working is fine. You are multiplying probability of surviving each round which is correct.

Comment: "*If the events were independent it would be $(5/6)\cdot (4/5)\cdots (1/2)=1/6$*"  Quite the opposite... it is *because they are dependent* that that calculation works.  The events "The first chamber is empty" and "The second chamber is empty" etc... are very much dependent events.  Had they been independent then it would have been $(5/6)\cdot (5/6)\cdot (5/6)\cdots$ noting that the probability that the $i$'th chamber is empty is the same regardless which chamber you ask about.

Comment: As for calculating $\Pr(F\mid E)$ in general, you need more information about $F$ and $E$.  As for calculating $\Pr(F\mid E)$ for your events "The first chamber is empty" and "The second chamber is empty" etc... they are calculated exactly as you had as being $\frac{4}{5}$ in your product above

Comment: As for calculating the answer to your original question... it is far easier to note that you survive if and only if the bullet is in the last chamber, the chamber which is not used.  Since the bullet is going to be in exactly one of the chambers and it is equally likely which of the six chambers it goes in, the answer is clearly $\dfrac{1}{6}$... no multiplication of anything necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do know that the total probability is 1/6, as if the cartridge looks like B-O-O-O-O-O,
You'll only survive if you start at the second slot and there are 6 slots.
As for the big question, if the events  were truly independent (i. e. reshuffling), the odds of each are 5/6 so it would be calculated as (5/6)^5. The previous move is factored in as doing (5/6)*(4/5)*(4/3)...*(1/2). The fact you have to survive the last move doesn't matter; think of it like this: if you have a friend shoot the gun 5 times instead of you, meaning all 5 slots get fired, it wouldn't matter as long as you keep the same cartridge position.